# I want the equation, equation number and the words w.p. 1-\delta on the same line with the latter right aligned

Tags: equations, align

Here is the aligning part:

```
\begin{align}
 & \leq d p \dots ~w.~p.~ 1 - \delta \\ 

& \leq \epsilon' \dots ~w.~p.~ 1 - \delta
\end{align}
```

[image]
I have tried using both align and flalign.

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  there seems to be something missing from your code.  to make it easier for us to help, please provide a compilable example that shows what you have now, beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Could you provide a little more context here?

Comment: Basically in the equation above I want to write w.p. 1-\delta and the equation number in the same line.

Comment: Remove the blank lines.

Comment: That was a formatting issue which creeped in but i dont have any blank lines in my tex file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\begin{align}
\leq d p         \tag{$\dots ~w.~p.~ 1 - \delta$}   &  \\
\leq \epsilon'   \tag{$\dots ~w.~p.~ 1 - \delta$}   &
\end{align}
```

Is this what you looking for?

Comment: No,  I want the w.p. 1-\delta and equation numbers on the same line

Comment: in the original version of your question is was stated differently. Please, clarify, how the `w.p. 1-\delta` is aligned.

Comment: @user75371, see edited answer.